# Echoing Data After Checking For Existence - In A Form

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use the 'or' way of checking for data in a blade template.

I do:

```
{{{ $data['news']->title or 'Default' }}}
```

The above gives me my data if it exists or default if it does not.

The problem I have is when using it inside a form fields default value:

```
{{ Form::text('username', $data['news']->title or 'Default') }}
```

It fails to work, if data does exist, it outputs 1, if not the page errors with undefined index: news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `or` sugared syntax only works when `echo`ing directly, not when passing it into a php function.

---

If you're sure that it has a `title` property, but it just might be empty, you can get away with this:

```
{{ Form::text('username', $data['news']->title ?: 'Default') }}
```

---

If you're unsure about the `title` property or the `news` key, but the `$data` variable definitely exists, you can use this:

```
{{ Form::text('username', data_get($data, 'news.title', 'Default')) }}
```

---

If the `$data` variable itself might be missing, you'll have to resort to this:

```
{{ Form::text('username', empty($data['news']->title) ? 'Default' : $data['news']->title) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a better operator just to output the $data if it exists, if it does not exist, output nothing?

Comment: @panthro Exactly the code I showed you, but replacing `'Default'` with `''`.

Comment: With `null` if you've an OCD and want to keep default parameters values the same as the framework's.